# Maximum ( or minimum ) of two functions on arbitrarily small interval.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, curves

Is there an example of two continuous functions say f and g ( they are continuous on whatever was the interval in hand ) , such that you can't find an interval ( no matter how small the interval was ) for which one function is bigger or equal than the other function for all values on that interval? Meaning that the two functions oscillate very rapidly about each other such that you can't find an interval where some function is bigger or equal than the other.

I know it seems obvious that this can't happen, but I'm not sure that I'm missing something that can make such functions exist. Since in many cases one can be mislead by intuition, I'm not satisfied in convincing myself it's obvious that this can't happen, so I want some kind of proof that this is impossible ( it leads to some kind of contradiction ).

Comment: If $f(x) \neq  g(x)$ then there must be an interval containing $x$ over which this is true.

Comment: @copper.hat I can't understand what is your point !

Comment: Either $f=g$ or there is some point at which they differ. Then continuity gives an interval containing the point such that the functions differ at all points in the interval.

Comment: yub that would do it thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can't happen. Consider $d(x):=f(x)-g(x)$. If it is identical zo zero, the two functions $f$ and $g$ are the same. So let's assume there is a non-zero vale of it:

$$d(x_0)=y_0 \neq 0$$.

Now since $f$ and $g$ are continous, there difference $d$ is as well. So there exists a $\delta_0 > 0$ such that $\lvert x - x_0 \rvert < \delta_0$ implies $\lvert d(x)-d(x_0) \rvert < \frac12 \lvert y_0 \rvert$, which implies $d(x) \neq 0$ (otherwise the LHS of the last inequalilty would be $\lvert 0 - d(x_0)\rvert = \lvert y_0 \rvert$). Because $d(x)$ is continuous, that means $d(x)$ can't change it's sign inside the interval $(x_0-\delta_0, x_0+\delta_0)$.

So $d(x)=f(x)-g(x)$ is either always positive or always negative in that interval, which is the same as saying that $f(x)$ is always bigger or always smaller than $g(x)$ in that interval.

Answer (score 0):

Hint If $f$, and $g$ are continuos functions with the same domain, then define 
$$F(x)=f(x)-g(x)$$ is a continue function, then for all interval $[a,b]$
$$[a,b]=[a,a_1]\cup[a_2,a_3]\cup\cdots\cup[a_i,b]$$ and $F(x)>0$ or $F(x)<0$ or $F(x)=0$ in each interval.